# Voice input for biking app

Tags: android, voice, wear-os

I am developing an Android Wear biking app. I am trying to enable the "Ok Google, Start cycling" into my app. It works perfectly if I say it to the phone, but not to my Moto360. Also in the Android Wear app, I am unable to choose my app as the default for "Start bike ride" Any suggestions?

This is what I have in my manifest, and it is based off of Google's example.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="vnd.google.fitness.TRACK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="vnd.google.fitness.activity/biking"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I searched other similar questions but didn't find a result.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Just to make sure: this intent filter is on an activity packaged in your Android Wear app?

Comment: No that was in the the phone app. I haven't actually made a separate application for Wear yet, all I've been doing is sending data over via a notification. Do I need to create a separate Wear Activity and repeat what I did above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a Wear app is a requirement for being listed in the available apps to register for a system provided voice intent on Android Wear and appear in the Android Wear application for choosing as the default for that voice action. Per the [Adding Voice Capabilities training](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html), you attach the appropriate `<intent-filter>` to an activity in your Wear app. One point of note if you aren't ready to provide a full Wear app is this section of the same page:

> When users speak the voice action, your app can filter for the intent that is fired to start an activity. If you want to start a service to do something in the background, show an activity as a visual cue and start the service in the activity. Make sure to call finish() when you want to get rid of the visual cue.

In your case, your activity could just display a visual cue that you are launching something (say using a `ConfirmationActivity` with an `OPEN_ON_PHONE_ANIMATION` from the [Wearable UI library](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/layouts.html#UiLibrary)) and then [send a message](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html) to your phone app, which would then listen for that message using a [`WearableListenerService`](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html#listener-service) and start the bike ride on the phone, posting your notification.

Note that a full Wear app with more customization is going to be expected as many apps, such as [Runtastic on Android Wear](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2014/09/runtastic-on-android-wear.html) add quite a few more abilities that augment the standard experience. While not out yet, an [upcoming release of Android Wear](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2014/09/android-wear-moving-forward-like.html) will be adding offline (i.e., without a phone) GPS support for Android Wear watches that have GPS ability (currently only the not yet released [Sony Smartwatch 3](http://blogs.sonymobile.com/press_release/sony-wearable-tech-smartwatch-3-smartband-talk/)) and of course those abilities will require a full Android Wear experience and cannot rely on a phone app (although details have not yet been released).

Comment: I've been working on a solution just like this one. My only question is that my app isn't running on the phone when the message is sent so will the message ever be received on the phone?

Comment: The WearableListenerService is specifically designed to receive Wear events including messages in the background

Comment: How about the MessageApi.MessageListener? That's the one I've been trying out

Comment: Right, that is the API to use if your app is already running and alive. The nice part about the WearableListenerService is that it is started automatically by the system when a new message/etc comes in, starting your app even if it is not running at all. Of course, the two do work well together - your wake up message could be the only thing your WearableListenerService cares about (ignoring others) and you have a MessageListener in particular components that handle other methods. Personally, I find the WearableListenerService more reliable so I LocalBroadcast the messages from there to others

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a launcher intent-filter to it; then, saying "OK Google, start [app name]" will start the app. The launcher filter is:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```